# Why does http.Get("http://[::]:1234") work?

Tags: go, ip

I was writing a test where I wanted an HTTP server to listen on a random port and then connect to this port. I wrote:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("foo")
})

listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":0")
fmt.Println(err)

httpServer := &http.Server{Handler: mux}
go httpServer.Serve(listener)

fmt.Println("http://" + listener.Addr().String())  

r, err := http.Get("http://" + listener.Addr().String())
fmt.Println(r)
fmt.Println(err)
```

I meant to write `net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")` but accidentally wrote `net.Listen("tcp", ":0")`.

For `"http://" + listener.Addr().String()` it prints:

> ```
> http://[::]:1709
> ```

where as far as I understand the "bracket colon colon bracket" means "all interfaces".

To my surprise, the `http.Get("http://[::]:1709")` works, it connects to the webserver and "foo" is printed.

How is "http://[::]:1709" a valid address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least on a Linux system, this results in a connection being made to localhost.

The address `::` is `IN6ADDR_ANY`, typically used when listening to listen for connections to any IPv6 address on the system. It's analogous to `INADDR_ANY`, also known as `0.0.0.0` in IPv4.

Occasionally someone attempts to use one of these addresses as the destination address for an outgoing connection. When this happens:

When making an outgoing connection to `0.0.0.0`, Linux actually connects from `127.0.0.1` to `127.0.0.1`.

Similarly, when making an outgoing connection to `::`, Linux actually connects from `::1` to `::1`. Here is an example, taken from one of my websites (which happens to be an IP address lookup tool):

```
[error@murloc ~]$ curl -k -H "Host: myip.addr.space" https://[::]:8443/
::1
```

For completeness, here is the IPv4 version:

```
[error@murloc ~]$ curl -k -H "Host: myip.addr.space" https://0.0.0.0:8443/
127.0.0.1
```

Note that this is OS-specific. You would have received [an error on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28230165/1068283).

Comment: I *am* on Windows.

Comment: That's a little strange, then. I would have expected you to get an error, the same as on IPv4. Maybe Microsoft changed something in IPv6.

Comment: Neither `ping` nor `curl`nor Chrome connect to it, but Go does.