# Java Socket fails to connect to "0.0.0.0" with NoRouteToHostException instead of ConnectionRefused

Tags: java, python, sockets, networking, linux-kernel

### Problem

When opening a socket to `IP: 0.0.0.0` and `Port: 37845` (just a random closed port) with java's socket class , the socket connect fails with a `java.net.NoRouteToHostException` on **Machine 1**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

I'm using this testcode:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Socket socket;

  // create a socket with a timeout
  SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", 37845);

  // create a socket
  socket = new Socket();

  // this method will block no more than timeout ms.
  int timeoutInMs = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds
  socket.connect(socketAddress, timeoutInMs);
  System.err.println("SUCCESS");
 }
}
```

### Expected

What , I'm actually expecting is a `java.net.ConnectException : Connection refused (Connection refused)` , which is also what I'm getting with another Cent OS machine, let's call it **Machine2**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

### Setup

**Machine1:**

```
[qa@jenkins-staging ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
[qa@jenkins-staging ~]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
[qa@jenkins-staging ~]$ uname -a
Linux jenkins-staging.fancydomain 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Machine2:**

```
[qa@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
[qa@localhost ~]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
[qa@localhost ~]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 29 14:49:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So it seems like the only difference is the kernel version.

### Additional things i've tried:

- I tried the "same" code with python , there i always get a 
  `ConnectionRefused` (on **Machine1** + **Machine2**)

  ```
  import socket
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.connect(("0.0.0.0", 37845))
  ```
- Pinging 0.0.0.0 on **Machine1** works as well and resolves to `127.0.0.1`
- Replacing `0.0.0.0` with `127.0.0.1` in the source code resolves the 
  problem , and `ConnectionRefused` (expected) is raised instead of `NoRouteToHostException`
- Disabling Firewalld, Disabling SELinux etc.

### Questions

1. Is this a java bug ? If so why is it working on **Machine2** even though 
   they are using the same jdk and same java version ?
2. Is this a Linux Kernel Bug ? If so why is it working with Python when i open 
   a socket to 0.0.0.0 but not with java ? I would assume the underlying 
   syscalls are the same.

### Clarification

In the example above i used a port which is closed , just for demonstration purposes. The same applies if there is an actual listening port on the machine then it will be `ConnectionRefused` vs `SUCCESS`

Comment: I don't know why you're testing this. It's invalid either way.

Comment: @user207421 originally because of this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/pull/720 , but right now it's just bothering me that the two machines behave differently and i can't tell why.

Answer (score 7):

`0.0.0.0` is a [special address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses), part of the special `0.0.0.0/8` range that means "current network" or "unspecified". You can't connect to it since it's undefined as a destination.

This is why you're getting a `NoRouteToHostException` - the address is simply not routable. You'll get a similar failure if you try to run `ping 0.0.0.0` or a similar command.

`ConnectionRefused` occurs when the remote machine actually refuses the connection, which is usually a sign that the remote machine doesn't have a listening socket or is behind a firewall.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419881 This answer explains that in practice you can specify it as a destination, but obviously as OP has found that doesn't always work as expected.

Comment: [This the documentation for the Java socket errors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html) which also explains the difference between them

Comment: @MarkReedZ I've never seen anything like that in practice, and unfortunately the answer you quoted doesn't provide any examples of where that happens. AFAIK, `0.0.0.0` can only be used as a source address when binding a socket. It makes absolutely no sense as a destination. If it does work on some platform, i'd consider it a bug.

Comment: Actually this is not true, please see the section "Additional things i've tried" there i mention that pinging ```0.0.0.0``` works . 
```[qa@jenkins-staging ~]$ ping 0.0.0.0
PING 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.255 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.113 ms
^C
--- 0.0.0.0 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.113/0.149/0.255/0.062 ms```

Comment: @Malt I've seen this in practice since this is used in the docker-plugin for jenkins, that's how i came across this bug/behaviour in the first place. The plugin was not working for my jenkins although there was another jenkins working with the same configuration. I did some debugging and so that's how i found out about this in the first place. 
Also you can try connecting to 0.0.0.0  in chrome on Ubuntu ,although it doesn't work in Windows 10 Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely install Wireshark on both machines, and compare all scenarios.

Specifically:

> https://superuser.com/questions/720851/connection-refused-vs-no-route-to-host
>
> "Connection refused" means that the target machine actively rejected the connection... one of the following things is likely the reason:
>
> - Nothing is listening on the port
> - The firewall is blocking the connection with REJECT
>
> The ICMP message, "no route to host," means that ARP cannot find the
>   layer-2 address for the destination host. Usually, this means that
>   that the host with that IP address is not online or responding.

Of course, this begs the question why Python behaves one way, and Java a different way ... on the same machine.

Again - I'd encourage you to look at Wireshark.  In particular, look at 1) the three-way TCP handshake, and 2) the ARP call that precedes it.

---

PS: As malt says above:

> 0.0.0.0 ... the address is simply not routable.

On Windows, you might get [WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL -The remote address is not a valid address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982562/)

Which begs the question why you're ever getting "ConnectionRefused".

Again - I'm definitely curious what Wireshark shows you.

Comment: For a non-routable destination, wireshark shouldn't show any packets. The OS's TCP/IP stack should return an error before sending anything.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

Regarding tracing the traffic, i did a tcpdump for arp requests but not even 1 arp request is send/received . 
Regarding tracing the TCP Handshake, as Malt mentioned, this doesn't make  sense imo since with the ```NoRouteToHostException``` there won't even be a TCP SYN packet since it fails before that.

Answer (score 0):

> I inlined the Code you provided and run it on windows 10 system, i get the correct exception

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new Socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", 37845), 10_0000);
    }
}
```

> Oracle JDK 8.0.202

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: That's interesting