# Python paramiko/sshtunnel code works fine under linux but fails under Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I have successfully gotten the following python paramiko/sshtunnel code to work properly under linux to tunnel to a port on a remote machine via an SSH tunnel. However, running the exact, same python code under Windows 10 fails. This is Python 3.9.5 in both cases.

First, the code itself ...

```
import sys
import json
import time
import queue
import socket
import paramiko
import sshtunnel
from threading import Thread

remotehost = 'remote-host-blah-blah-blah.net'
remoteport = 9999
pkeyfile   = os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_rsa')

def main():
    pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(pkeyfile)
    with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
        (remotehost, 22),
        ssh_username='remoteusername',
        ssh_pkey=pkey,
        compression=True,
        remote_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', remoteport)
    ) as remote:
        connecthost = remote.local_bind_host
        connectport = remote.local_bind_port
        return runit(connecthost, connectport)
    return 1

def runit(connecthost, connectport):
    client = None

    while True:
        try:
            client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            client.connect((connecthost, connectport))
            output(f'\nconnected: {connecthost}:{connectport}')
            break
        except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(1.0)
            print(f'!!! retrying {connecthost}:{connectport} because of {e}')

    # If we made it here, we are properly connected through
    # the tunnel. This works under linux, but we never get
    # here under Windows 10. The code which follows is not
    # pertinent to this Stackoverflow question, so I have
    # left out the remaining code in this program.
```

And this is the error that keeps printing ...

> !!! retrying 0.0.0.0:53906 because of [WinError 10049] The requested
> address is not valid in its context

The "53906" port is different each time I run this, of course.

Also, under Windows 10, I can go to Power Shell while this python program is running, and I can run the following, in which case I indeed get connected to the port and see the remote data ...

```
telnet localhost 53906
```

This seems to imply that there is something about the way that python is trying to connect to that socket which is causing the error.

Can anyone see what I might need to change in my python code to get this to work properly under Windows 10?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem and fixed it.

These two lines return `connecthost` = '0.0.0.0' and a random value for `connectport`:

```
        connecthost = remote.local_bind_host
        connectport = remote.local_bind_port
```

However, if I force `connecthost` to be '127.0.0.1' in the `client.connect` call, my code works fine.

I'm guessing that Windows 10 must handle '0.0.0.0' differently from how linux handles it. If so, then perhaps `sshtunnel.open_tunnel` under Windows should be changed to return '127.0.0.1' instead of '0.0.0.0'.

Anyway, this is working now.

Comment: The `0.0.0.0` means that Paramiko/sshtunnel listens on all interfaces. On Windows you cannot connect to `0.0.0.0`. See for example [Socket.connect() to 0.0.0.0: Windows vs. Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11982562/850848).

Comment: Thank you. I figured it must be something like that. In this case, I think that`remote.local_bind_host` should not be returned from `open_tunnel` as '0.0.0.0' under Windows, but rather, as '127.0.0.1', or else code like this will always fail under Windows.